# Filebeat Invalid Frame Type Error

Tags: amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, filebeat

I have ELK stack running on AWS and i wanted to get logs from my windows PC as a filebeat stream so i installed filebeat in that windows host when i run my logstash configuration i get the fallowing error .

```
[2018-05-24T06:34:18,140][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid Frame Type, received: 84, from: /[My WindowsHost IP]:51701
[2018-05-24T06:34:34,296][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid Frame Type, received: 69, from: /[My WindowsHost IP]:51702
[2018-05-24T06:34:34,297][INFO ][org.logstash.beats.BeatsHandler] Exception: org.logstash.beats.BeatsParser$InvalidFrameProtocolException: Invalid Frame Type, received: 84, from: /[My WindowsHost IP]:51702
```

because its getting my windows host ip, logstash is getting the filebeat stream but port number is different from one to another as the stream goes

but in my windows host filebeat config has logstash output like this

```
hosts: ["http://AWS-EIP:5044"]
```

Any ideas ???